# Chartjs stack overflow max value

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js

I'm using chartjs with react.
when i have two axises with "stack" mode and one of them has min and max values,
the chart is overflows the max value.
i want that values over max value will not be shown at all on the chart.
is it possible to cat them?

[image]

Comment: Filter your data source before render.

Comment: filter the data is an option. but for me it looks like a bug in chart.js

Comment: I think it's a bug. Maybe you can submit an issue it to the project.

Comment: A PR has been submitted to fix it: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/10691